# Empty result when string splited using pattern

Tags: java, regex, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have the follow code:

```
String generalRequest = "4+6*12/3";
String[] operatorsLine = generalRequest.split("[0-9]+");
```

In result, I have the surplus empty value in `operatorsLine`:

> "", "+", "*", "/"

Hovewer I desire an outcome:

> "+", "*", "/"

---

**How to skip adding `""` value into array, using `String.split()` method?**

Comment: What  is your desired outcome?

Comment: @Ghanima "+", "*", "/"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
String[] operatorsLine = Arrays.stream(generalRequest.split("[0-9]+"))
                               .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                               .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the next Compile error:

Error:(51, 102) java: method toArray in interface java.util.stream.Stream<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.IntFunction<A[]>
  found: java.lang.String[]
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) A
    (argument mismatch; java.lang.String[] cannot be converted to java.util.function.IntFunction<A[]>)

Comment: in `new String[0]`

Comment: solved! Thank you, friend). I also always have the trouble wits function generators)

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help:)

Answer (score 3):

In this case, where all you need is single character operators, 
removing all digits from the string and splitting with an empty string as a delimeter would work:

```
String generalRequest = "4+6*12/3";
String[] operatorsLine = generalRequest.replaceAll("\\d", "").split("");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(operatorsLine));
```

This prints:

```
[+, *, /]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about supplying the second parameter to the [`split(String regex, int limit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) method and limiting it with 2 output fields and again splitting it:

```
String generalRequest = "4+6*12/3";
String[] operatorsLine = (generalRequest.split("\\d+", 2)[1]).split("\\d+");
```

The first split will output an array: `["", "+6*12/3"]`, then take the first index and split it again with the same Regex.

The final value of `operatorsLine` will be `[+,*,/]`